# Template classes and base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, base-class

I have a base class `IStructure` which is derived by many classes.

Some of these classes 'reference' other `IStructure` classes. For example, my class `class GuiButton : public IStructure` has a member of `Textstring` (which derives from `IStructure`, as well).

Now I'm just glistening over this so I can get to the point, so this may seem weird to some of you. I would like to have a template class 'Reference' that references an `IStructure`. For example:

```
class GuiButton : public IStructure {
public:
    Reference<Textstring> Text;
};
```

I know some of you might be wondering why I just don't do `Textstring* Text`. This is because some of these references are "external". The `Reference` template class only holds information about the `IStructure` (ie. Name, etc.). Some of these classes are insanely big and it would be pointless to instantiate that whole class to only use the `Name` property and what not. Does that make sense?

So now to my question:

```
class Textstring : public IStructure;
```

I can reference a `Textstring` by using my template:

```
Reference<Textstring> Text;
```

Now here's the issue: Some methods I have require me to upcast to `IStructure', for example:

```
void RegisterReference(Reference<IStructure> &reference);
```

So I couldn't do this:

```
Reference<Textstring> txt("TextName");
RegisterReference(txt); // error
```

I know I can cure this by not having `Reference` be a template, but I would really like to because it makes it easier to understand and know what type the reference is.

What are some ways I can accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

-Alex

Comment: Can RegisterReference be templatized? as in template<typename T> void RegisterReference(Reference<T> &reference);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your function a template on the type parameter of the `Reference`, like this:

```
template <typename R>
void RegisterReference(Reference<R> &r);
```

Comment: Ok, I tried `template<class TIStructure> void addReference(void* resolvePoint, Reference<TIStructure> referenced, unsigned int fileType);`, but it's giving me an error `syntax error: identifier 'Reference'`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is the definition of `Reference` template class available at the point where you declare `addReference`?

Comment: Eek - that could be it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As @dasblinkenlight suggest, you could templatize your library functions. Or, you can add some "variance" to the `Reference` class:

```
template<typename T>
class Reference
{
    // ...
public:
    template<typename U>
    Reference(Reference<U> const & r) {
        // "copy" r into *this
    }
};
```

Or with conversion operators

```
template<typename T>
class Reference
{
    // ...
public:
    template<typename U>
    operator Reference<U>() {
        // convert Reference<T> into Reference<U>
    }
};
```

The downside of this approach is that you're actually creating new objects each time you need to upcast.

### Edit

Thanks to Luc Danton for pointing this out. The code as I have written handles way more than upcasts. It'll do whatever conversions are available. To restrict things a little more nicely, we could do something like this (in C++11):

```
template<typename T>
class Reference
{
    // ...
public:
    template<typename U,
      typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value>::type>
    Reference(Reference<U> const & r) {
        // "copy" r into *this
    }
};
```

Comment: @walrii: Nope, that's @dasblinkenlight's answer. Mine only deals with modifying the `Reference` class itself via conversion operators and constructors.

Comment: To be fair I don't think there's anything wrong with a constraint on `std::is_convertible` -- which includes derived-to-base. The point being avoiding no constraints at all: that would make `Reference<char*>` convertible to `Reference<int>` or all sorts of nonsense.